# Getting raw resource (sound) in non-activity class

Tags: java, android, singleton, android-resources

I'm trying to create a singleton class that will be responsible for playing game sounds. I created a singleton class `GameSounds` with a method `playSound()`. In the res folder I have a a subfolder 'raw' with a file `letter_found.mp3`.

This is the source code of the `GameSounds` class I wrote:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class GameSounds extends Application {

    private static GameSounds gameSounds = new GameSounds();
    private static MediaPlayer soundPlayer;
    private static Context mContext;
    private static int mySoundId = R.raw.letter_found;

    private GameSounds() {
        mContext = this;
    }

    public static GameSounds getInstance() {
        return gameSounds;
    }

    public static void playSound() {
        soundPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, mySoundId);
        soundPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work as I'm getting the following error message:

> "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference"

I don't understand why this is happening. I tried to search Stackoverflow but couldn't find a solution.

Any help/explanation is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a Singleton holding an Application `Context` (NOT Activity context) but practically you have to set this context before you use your singleton which can be enforced by throwing exceptions. See below example code.

```
public class GameSounds {
    private static Context sContext;

    public static void setContext(Context context) {
        if (context == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("context cannot be null!");
        }

        // In order to avoid memory leak, you should use application context rather than the `activiy`
        context = context.getApplicationContext();
        if (context == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("context cannot be null!");
        }

        sContext = context;
    }

    private static Context getContext() {
        if (sContext != null) {
            return (Context)sContext;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("sContext was not set yet! Please call method setContext(Context context) first.");
    }

    // the rest of other methods. e.g. playSounds()
    private static GameSounds gameSounds = new GameSounds();
    private GameSounds() {

    }

    public static GameSounds getInstance() {
        return gameSounds;
    }


    public void playSound() {

        Context context = getContext();

        soundPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, mySoundId);
        soundPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't **inherit `Application` class** unless you try to use Singleton pattern. Because Application is base class which contains all other components such as activities and services.

Instead, GameSound class should contain `Context` object and proper constructor.

Example)

```
public class GameSounds {

    private GameSounds gameSounds;
    private MediaPlayer soundPlayer;
    private WeakReference<Context> mContext;
    private int mySoundId = R.raw.letter_found;

    private GameSounds(Context context) {
        mContext = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

    public GameSounds getInstance(Context context) {
        if (gameSounds == null) {
            gameSounds = new GameSounds(context);
        }

        return gameSounds;
    }

    public void playSound() {
        soundPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext.get(), mySoundId);
        soundPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

In this code, there is `WeakReference<Context>` instead of Context. WeakReference is used to **prevent memory leaks** because memory leaks can occur if you have an instance outside the activity.

To play sound, execute `GameSounds.getInstance(this).playSound();` is fine.

If Context can't provide when try to play sound, implement `initialize` methods and called in Application class can be ok.

```
public class GameSounds {

    private static GameSounds gameSounds;
    private MediaPlayer soundPlayer;
    private WeakReference<Context> mContext;
    private int mySoundId = R.raw.letter_found;

    private GameSounds(Application context) {
        mContext = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

    public static void initialize(Application context) {
        if (gameSounds == null) {
            gameSounds = new GameSounds(context);
        }
    }

    public static GameSounds getInstance() {
        if (gameSounds == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("You need to initialize this code by GameSound.initialize(this) in application class");
        }

        return gameSounds;
    }

    public void playSound() {
        soundPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext.get(), mySoundId);
        soundPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

In this case, you should make [Application class](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class) and initialize GameSound class by `GameSound.initialize(this)` in Application class.

To play sound, `GameSound.getInstance().playSound()` is fine.